# bind app id services to ibm containers service

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-appid

Is there a way to bind my app id service to my ibm containers service cluster?  If not, are there plans to add this in the future, or is there a way I can configure my liberty app server to access it with put using bx cs cluster-service-bind?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can bind App ID to your IBM Container Service Kubernetes cluster.

1. Provision an instance of App ID
2. Use `bx service list` to see list of services, you might need to target your org/space
3. Use `bx cs cluster-service bind {cluster-name} {kube-namespace} {appid-instance-name-or-guid}`
4. Use `kubectl get secrets` to see a new secret created by step 3 above. The secret name should be `binding-{appid-instance-name}`